# How would molluscs work under an amoebic sea?

Tags: creature-design, environment, planets

If an amoebic sea like on Darwin IV existed, could there be something like molluscs beneath the surface or on the shore and how would the work give the fact that the sea is alive and doesn't seem to recede with the tide?

Comment: There would almost certainly be some kind of parasitic creatures.

Answer (score 2):

***Behold, the Killer Snail:***

Functionally, molluscs are more likely to behave like predators. All food is from the sea, so everything would need a way to get at the resources controlled by the sea. The sea would actively and aggressively defend itself from these creatures, so a formidable defense (like a mechanically and chemically resistant shell to retreat to) would be invaluable. Sea Amoeboids would try to crush, suffocate, dissolve or encapsulate predators. Shells often have air pockets as a reserve against this. Some sort of raspy tongue to gouge out food from the sea would be good, and the ability to move away to avoid encapsulation would be useful.

Of the molluscs, the snail fits all these criteria quite well. They would rasp away at the outside of the sea, digging onto the flesh. Then they would need to avoid a lethal response from the defensive Amoebic Sea, withdrawing into their shells if they can't readily get away.